# Golang read fixed width text file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/o1egl/fwencoder) to read a fixed width file from S3. It requires an io.Reader, and so far this is what I've got:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/o1egl/fwencoder"
)

type leRecord struct {
    fullName       string
    firstName      string
    lastName       string
    primaryAddress string
    city           string
    state          string
    zipcode        string
    MailKey        string
}

func main() {
    getObjectReturnMaps("key", "bucket")

}

func getObjectReturnMaps(key, bucket string) {
    // Initialize an AWS session with configured credentials
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Define client
    s3Client := s3.New(sess)

    // Using the key, get the object from the bucket
    obj, err := s3Client.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Read the body, parse it into variable
    var records []leRecord

    reader := bufio.NewReader(obj.Body)
    err = fwencoder.UnmarshalReader(reader, &records)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(records)
}
```

however printing the records variable returns blanks:

```
[{       } {       } {       } {       } {       }......]
```

but if I print the reader it clearly has values:

```
&{[32 32 88 10 84 82 69 65 68 87 69 76 76 32 32 68 65 78 73 69 76 32 32 82... ]
```

So I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. Is it because im passing a `bufio.Reader` instead of an `io.Reader`?

EDIT:

Here is some sample data:

```
John                        Smith                       J                       123 Street Name                       SampleTown                       NY                       12345                       X
Jane                        Smith                       J                       456 Name Street                       Anywhere                         TX                       78901                       X
```

There are no column headers in these files

Comment: The fields in your struct need to be exported (start with a capital letter) for the `Unmarshal` to be able to use them. As is, it finds no fields (other than MailKey) so has nothing to unmarshal into.

Comment: Changing the fields in my struct to have capital letters has no effect unfortunately.

Comment: You should show sample data, we can't tell if your struct is even correct. In addition to exported field names, you need to make sure the names match the column names, or use struct tags to override them.

Comment: updated. The files have no column names

Comment: You should double check the [fwencoder](https://godoc.org/github.com/o1egl/fwencoder) docs, but I don't think it works without column headers.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Marc, [fwencoder](https://github.com/o1egl/fwencoder), considers the first line of the file as header.

https://github.com/o1egl/fwencoder/blob/8a2f1ab8210ee2018fd171ea1bea94eaa64d043c/decoder.go#L120

```
if !isHeaderParsed {
        isHeaderParsed = true
        headersLength = len(lineRunes)
        columns, err = parseHeaders(line, columnNames)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        continue
    }
```

So if you can control the files written to s3  try adding the header or if you are sure about the  order of column you can rely on "encoding/csv" something like [here](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-read-tab-delimited-file-with-encoding-csv-package)